# "Merge" paths and display all matchs in one line

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I need help, I have that :

```
/usr/include/slang.h:include
/usr/include/slang.h:star
/usr/include/slang.h:load
/usr/include/byteswap.h:include
```

and I must merge to have result here in shell:

```
/usr/include/slang.h include star load
/usr/include/byteswap.h include
```

How can I do ?

Comment: `awk -F':' '{a[$1] = a[$1]OFS$2};END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}'  input`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat merge.txt 
/usr/include/slang.h:include
/usr/include/slang.h:star
/usr/include/slang.h:load
/usr/include/byteswap.h:include

$ cat merge.sh 
#!/bin/bash

for path in $(awk -F':' '{print $1}' merge.txt | uniq)
do 
    values=$(grep "${path}" merge.txt | awk -F':' '{print $NF}' | tr '\n' ' ')
    echo "${path}" "${values}"
done
```

Output:

```
$ ./merge.sh 
/usr/include/slang.h include star load 
/usr/include/byteswap.h include
```